# How would you use Codemirror documents to get multiple editors?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm trying to add tabs to the Codemirror editor to have multiple editors just by the switch of a tab.

I got this basic implementation working but couldn't make any progress https://codepen.io/mottox2/pen/wmGopW

The CodeMirror manual says to do this
https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_doc

```
CodeMirror.Doc(text: string, mode: Object, firstLineNumber: ?number, lineSeparator: ?string)
```

But I have no idea where I'd put that line of code

Comment: That line creates a new document for the defined editor. If you want multiple editors within a page then you need to define multiple editors using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question, is this what you're looking for? 
[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/xxwvVva)

```
var editors = document.getElementsByClassName('editor');
for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
  var self = editors[i];
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(self, {
    mode: "javascript",
    lineNumbers: true,
    autoRefresh: true
  });
  editor.save();
}

var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');

for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  var self = tabs[i];
  self.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var data = this.getAttribute('data-tab');
    document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane.active')[0].classList.remove('active');
    document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane[data-pane="'+data+'"]')[0].classList.add('active');
    document.querySelectorAll('.tab.active')[0].classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
  });
}
```

Define multiple editors using a loop, create some tabs to hide / show each editor.